# multiple instances of vue js?

Tags: laravel-5, webpack, vuejs2

I have just updated my environment, from using `vueJS` by pulling in the script from the official CDN, to an installed version, with `npm` under a `laravel` environment.

I am now, getting two notes about running in developement instead of one.

Does this mean that I'm instantiating `Vue` twice?

[image]

I do have the `import Vue from 'vue'` in two places. Once in my main `.js` file and the other one in some `bus.js` which looks like

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default new Vue()
```

Comment: Are you still including the file from the cdn?

Comment: No, I have removed that one.